# MySQL get previous and next record based on id order by listorder

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a next and previous navigation using php and mysql. My problem is I can't make it work. Here's what I tried so far:

**Query:**

```
select * from blog_entry where deleted='n' and isDisplayed='y' and b_id = (select max(b_id) from blog_entry where deleted='n' and isDisplayed='y' and b_id < 154) order by listorder desc
```

**Table**

[image]

So in my page if I'm on entry number 154( b_id: 154 ), clicking the next button will show content from b_id 152, same thing for previous record. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @Strawberry: whatever you read, this question is not about pagination

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give you record no 153

```
select * from blog_entry where deleted='n' and isDisplayed='y' and b_id = (select max(b_id) from blog_entry where deleted='n' and isDisplayed='y' and b_id < 154) order by listorder desc limit 1
```

Below query will give you record no 155

```
select * from blog_entry where deleted='n' and isDisplayed='y' and b_id = (select max(b_id) from blog_entry where deleted='n' and isDisplayed='y' and b_id > 154) order by listorder  limit 1
```

Comment: If I'm on b_id: 154, I should get 152 for next and 140 for previous. I'm following the listorder to get the b_id for next and previous record. thanks for your comment though :) @Ronak

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select * from `blog_entry` where `deleted`='n' and `isDisplayed`='y' order by `b_id` desc limit 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do half of it in the original select where you read the blog_entries. The other solutions need 2 extra selects per row, which is much more. The other half (storing "next") I would do in php after reading the selected values.

Beware the right order of the select fields:

```
set @last_id=null;

select * from 
(
    select @last_id as last_id, (@last_id := b.id) as id, b.listorder, b.<content>
    from blog_entry b where deleted='n' and isDisplayed='y'
    order by b.id
) as tech_subsel
order by listorder;
```

EDIT: php-part

```
$result = array();

while ($row = <read row>){
    if(isset($result[$row['last_id']]){
          $result[$row['last_id']]['next_id'] = $row['id'];
    }
    $result[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

then you have last_id and next_id in one scan.